# ErrorException [ Notice ]: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, kohana

Не получается вывести данные из базы... Выдает ошибку
[image]

Код виджета

```
class Controller_Widgets_Carousel extends Controller_Template {

    public $template = 'widgets/w_view_carusel';

    public function action_index()
    {
        $carouselsql = ORM::factory('material')
                        ->limit(1)
                        ->order_by('view', 'DESC')
                        ->find_all();
        //Вывод в шаблон
        $carousel = View::factory('widgets/w_view_carusel', array(
                        'carousel' => $carouselsql,
                        ));
        $this->template->carousel = $carousel;
    }
```

}

Вывод такой

```
<div class="carousel">
    <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
<?foreach($carousel as $vivod):?>
        <li>
            <div class="home-box dark">
                <h4><?=$vivod->title?></h4>
                <a href="/media/images/bigphoto.jpg" class="fancycaption photo-overlay fancybox-photo">
                    <img class="fade" src="/media/photos/120x200/1.jpg" width="150" height="100" alt="carousel thumb" />
                </a>
                <div class="carousel-info">
                    <a class="carousel-link" href="#">Скачать</a>
                    <a class="carousel-link" href="#">Подробнее</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
<?endforeach?>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: В тексте ошибки ведь и файл:строчка были указаны

Answer (score 2):

Да не вопрос, ошибка явная, правда скриншот неудачный.

```
<h4><?=$vidod=>title?></h4>
```

а должно быть

```
<h4><? echo $vidod->title;?></h4>
```

**//upd**

ну есть еще вариант

```
foreach ($carousel as $key => $val)
        echo $val['title'];
```

В общем выведи вообще что передается в шаблон

```
var_dump($carousel);
```

Эм, смотри что еще может быть

у тебя
    public $template = 'widgets/w_view_carusel'; // это шаблон вывода.

```
 $carousel = View::factory('widgets/w_view_carusel', array(
                        'carousel' => $carouselsql,
                        ));
        $this->template->carousel = $carousel;
```

Ты сначала в переменную загоняешь шаблон где происходит формирование его, а потом берешь и в этот же шаблон впихиваешь только что сгенерированный шаблон. и вот на это он и ругается наверное. Я с коханой не дружу, но по логике вещей вывод значит сделан неправильно.

т.е. допустим в yii нужен render()

```
$this->render('widgets/w_view_carusel',array('carousel '=>$carouselsql));
```

А у тебя реально получается каша, если я правильно понимаю логику коханы.

Попробуй сделать так для проверки

```
//Вывод в шаблон
        $carousel = View::factory('widgets/w_view_carusel', array(
                        'carousel' => $carouselsql,
                        ));
        echo $carousel; // так вот, что будет?!
```

Comment: да нет...так вообще синтаксическая ошибка!

Comment: обновил ответ.

Comment: у меня так и есть<?=$vivod->title?> Так всегда работала, а вот в виджете не хочет((

Comment: И обнови свой скриншот значит, ибо на скриншоте ошибка!

т.е. на нем именно ошибка в **=>** поменять на  **->** если выползает другая ошибка её в студию!

Comment: че то с передоваемым массивом...после var_dump вот что object(View)#36 (2) { ["_file:protected"]=> string(64) "W:\domains\lumia.su\application\views\widgets/w_view_carusel.php" ["_data:protected"]=> array(1) { ["carousel"]=> object(Database_MySQL_Result)#38 (7) { ["_internal_row:protected"]=> int(0) ["_query:protected"]=> string(569) "SELECT `material`.`id` AS `id`, `material`.`post` AS `post`, `material`.`category` AS `category`, и так далее...

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: я попробовал убрать из виджета и поставить в контроллер...все работает...

Answer (score 1):

Читайте текст ошибки.
Там ясно написано, что попытка получить свойство от переменной не являющейся объектом.
Посмотрите, что у Вас в `$vivod`.
Хотя бы с помощью `print_r`.

Comment: выводит то же что и вверху